# How to make a Odata batch call in karate

Tags: odata, karate

I need to make Odata call to fech the results from downsream APIs. I am using karate to test our APIs. But now i need to fech the data from downstream APIand compare it with our APIs result. My problem is downstream APIs are Odata request. Can i make Odata batch request from karate. if yes how?

Request header is: Content-Type = 'multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_01'
and  Request body is:

--batch_01
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET test(test1='ABC',test2='12345')/abc/?$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/json

--batch_01--

Even i am not able to read the request body in karate?

Adding screenshot  here how the request shown in postman

[image]

[image]

Comment: if it works over HTTP Karate can do it, but your question is not clear to me. maybe others will be able to help you

Comment: Yes Peter its over http. I added the postman screenshots here to give some clearity. I want to automate this using karate.

Comment: @KarateCoder I am also trying to automate OData related APIs using Karate. Getting different kinds of errors. Were you able to successfully test a POST/PUT request with OData?

Comment: for others looking for how to do this using karate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/921#issuecomment-544161221 - and @KhajaMohammed you never updated that thread :|

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond earlier, I did leave my comment now. Agree that it's rare case and may be Karate don't have to respond natively. Thanks for your suggestions