# Can we limit the number of request hits per second in karate

Tags: karate

I  am using karate 0.9.0. I need to limit the request hits to 5 per second in my test suite due to threshold limit at gateway. is it possible in karate or not? If yes, how?

Comment: if you found an answer to this question, please add and update: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56242361/143475 - else delete the question

Comment: no peter, i did not get any answer for this till now. I will update it as soon i will find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the suggestion - [`configure headers`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers) as a JavaScript function. Within the function body - use a Java singleton (and a static method) to track how many requests have been sent and how much "sleep" needs to be added to maintain the required throttling / threshold.

You will need some Java skills to do this, all the best. The documentation has details on how to [call Java code](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java).

Comment: I used sleep method to limit the request hit